# How to disable a button click in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have made a simple calculator using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The problem I face is that when the input field is empty (not having any number in it), the arithmetic operators (-,+,/,%,=) should be disabled.

Comment: Tips: [EventTarget.addEventListener() for check if change value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - [disabled element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)

Comment: Have you tried searching for that question? This seems like something that has been covered rather a lot on this site and the internet in general.